# React Native Sprite Sheets

Tags: react-native, 2d-games

Is it possible to do sprite sheet based animation with React Native? It appears that you have to load individual images, rather than a sprite sheet.

Comment: wrote something instead, here it is [react-native-animated-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-sprite) and at [github](https://github.com/micahrye/react-native-animated-sprite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite a single sprite sheet, but [react-native-sprite](https://github.com/williamngan/react-native-sprite) bridges UIImageView to support animating a sequence of images natively.

It might be possible to bring SpriteKit to react-native. In that case, you can compile a single sprite sheet using [texture atlas](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-texture_atlas/AboutTextureAtlases/AboutTextureAtlases.html).

Comment: I wrote something similar to react-native-sprite, thanks for the info.

Comment: @HamicornFury would you be willing to share the code you wrote? I have a need for this at the moment.

Comment: sure, just made it easy to get [react-native-animated-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-sprite) and at [github](https://github.com/micahrye/react-native-animated-sprite)